# Can I create ecommerce Website using plainphp + soap API + Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, soap-api-v2, mvc

Can I create eCcommerce Website using plainphp or any php MVC framework + soap API + Magento

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento itself is a ready to use eCommerce CMS written in PHP & supports SOAP API. So, you just need to install it and start using.

Comment: Thanks Rahul but while loading a eCommere Magento website it take a lot of time to load so i thought that we can also use API's just to fetch products and data but will that save my load time ??

Comment: If you don't have complex scenarios like special price, group price discounts, etc. then you can go for PHP site with Magento  at back-end, but, I will recommend to optimize Magento so that the loading time gets less.

Comment: PHP site with Magento at back-end this is what i am asking for :-) it will be great if you have any examples to share

Comment: Okay, so, what kind of examples you require. Magento provides SOAP API web service structure here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalog.html You need to call each web services at desired pages maintaining the flow of eCommerce

Comment: Thanks Rahul are there any readymade examples ??

Comment: Not really, there's no ready-made examples are available, you need to start it from scratch